# PayPal integration Magento CE 1.7

Tags: magento, paypal

I have a store in which base currency is INR and want PayPal for international payments, how can we achieve that? Store is based on Magento CE1.7.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal doesn't support INR as a currency yet. You would need to pass a `currency_code` value to PayPal that we support. I'm not sure if Magento supports INR either.

I found a Magento wiki page that goes into detail on how they handle currencies with PayPal:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/paypal_supported_currencies